# Read data from a local JSON file with data binding in ngOnInit() results in undefined variable

Tags: json, angular, typescript, parsing

I am trying to get a data from json file in the `assets` folder, and then assign this data to a variable that will be binded to another `@Input` variable of a child componenet.

- **Code**

Based on multiple solutions on the net, I retrieve my JSON data this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class JSONService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public fromJSON(jsonFileName: string): Observable<any[]> {
      let result: any[] = new Array();
      let pathToJson: string = "assets/" + jsonFileName + ".json";

      return this.http.get(pathToJson).map(data => {
        let result: any[] = new Array();
        // Apply some treatment on data and push it to the result array
        return result;
      });
    }
}
```

I then call my service in the `ngOnInit()` method of the parent component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonService.fromJSON("users.json").subscribe(fields => {
      this.fields= fields;
      console.log(this.fields); // Log (I): this.fields is well defined
    });
    console.log(this.fields); // Log (II): this.fields is undefined
}
```

Where the variable `fields` is binded to a child component:

```
<child-component [childFields] = "fields"></child-component>
```

- **Problem**

The problem that I am facing is that the asynchronous call to the `fromJSON` method causes `this.fields` to be undefined at some point of the lifecycle of the page execution (`Log (II)` from the code above), and this causes to send an undefined value of the `this.fields` variable to the child component.

How to avoid to have an undefined value of the `fields` variable, and make sure that the child component is always loaded with the data from the json file?

Comment: Use a resolver in your route who make the service call and receive the response in the component constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add *ngIf to check if the data is loaded

```
<child-component *ngIf="fields" [childFields] = "fields"></child-component>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class JSONService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public fromJSON(jsonFileName): Observable<any[]> {
      console.warn('Retriving Default Data from File.......');
    return this.http.get(filename)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
    }
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || [];
  }

  private handleError(error: any) {
        const errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
          error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
        console.error(errMsg);
        console.log('Server Error!');
        return Observable.throw(errMsg);
      }
}
```

### parent.component.ts

```
constructor(public jsonService: jsonService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

          this.jsonService.fromJSON('assets/users.json').subscribe(
          function (success) {
            this.data = success;
           this.datahandle(success);
          },
          error => console.log('Getting Server Data Error :: ' + 
    JSON.stringify(error)));

}
datahandle(jsonData){

console.log('check data' + JSON.stringify(jsonData)); <-----check data

// may parse your jsonData  if required
this.fields = jsonData ;

let keys = Object.keys(jsonData);
console.log(keys);


}
}
```

### parent.component.html

```
<child-component *ngIf="fields" [childFields] = "fields"></child-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your component is somewhat like below

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public fields: any[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jsonService.fromJSON("users.json").subscribe(fields => {
      this.fields = fields;
      console.log(this.fields); // Log (I): this.fields is well defined
    });
    console.log(this.fields); // Log (II): this.fields is undefined
  }
}
```

Then you can either initialize **fields** with an empty array

```
public fields: any[] = [];
```

OR in template

```
<child-component *ngIf="fields" [childFields]="fields"></child-component>
```